# WSO2 ESB. Differences between v. 5.0.0 and v. 4.9.0. Send mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB v. 4.9.0 *send* metiator did not terminate sequence where it is and all parent sequences and at last proxy service or API. So, in code :

```
...
<!-- This seqience has send mediator -->
<sequence key="ElabaFtpFileWrite"/>
<!-- This sequence has send mediator -->
<sequence key="ElabaSendMail"/>
<!-- for instance, some mediator or another logic -->
<log level="full"/>  
...
```

second sequence and log mediator are always performed.

On the contrary, in version 5.0.0. nether second sequence nor log mediator are performed.

According to the documentation about send mediator of v. 5.0.0 second behavior is right. But why in v. 4.9.0 send worked in different way and I didn't find any notice about such issue.

I think I somehow did not notice because I am not very experienced user of WSO2 products.

I changed *send* mediator to *call* mediator in first and second sequences and then log mediator is performed.

Is such resolution right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/commit/dc78d18210f3cbd8d2eb04bcd7236658ee3731f4 : on Jun 29, 2016, send mediator has been changed to return "false" (instead of "true") to avoid remaining mediators to be executed

The documentation reflect this : compare https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Send+Mediator and https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Send+Mediator you will notice this add-on :

*Do not add any mediator configurations after Send mediator in the same sequence, because WSO2 ESB does not process them. Any mediator configuration after the Send mediator should go to the outSequence or receive sequence.*